# What arguments are necessary to start up a program in Windows from the Task Scheduler closed?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, application-launch

By default, if you manually set a program to start up, the main window gets launched and opened, hence the main question in the title.  At least minimized would somewhat be helpful but still not ideal.  I know this can be done with a shortcut but if it can be done directly with whatever pertaining executable, specifically to have it either start closed (in the background) or have the window automatically closed upon getting opened, that would be what I'm mainly looking for.  Thanks!

[Action window in Task Scheduler for starting a program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsu15.png)

Comment: Do you have to interact with the window in some way? If not, run it as system. (check box "run with highest privileges") and you won't see a thing of it at all.

Comment: It will likely depend a lot on the specific application. If you were to give examples of the application(s) you hope to do this with, it could help us get you a better answer.

Comment: Sure.  One example is the one you see in that image link in the original post (7+ Taskbar Tweaker) and the other ones (on some systems)  would be CCleaner and DVDFab Passkey Lite.  In all cases, when you launch the program manually, it opens up a window in the taskbar.  I would simply want it to automatically be closed.  I imagine the arguments for that would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the task scheduler to launch the windows scripting host instead.

In turn, the windows scripting host can start the program any way you like to include hidden (not just minimized).

**First**, you need to create a javascript or vbscript 'launcher' for your exe.  You will do this by creating a text file "somewhere".  For this sample, I will call it "mySampleAppRunner.js"

Populate it with your version of the following:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Run(
        "C:\\yourPath\\your.exe -f -u -n'", 
        0 /* SW_HIDE */, 
        false /* bWaitOnReturn */
        );
```

For other options than SW_HIDE (aka hide der window), see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow

**Next**, Add new "Task Scheduler" task

General:

- Name it

Trigger:

- Up to you, I suggest At log on -> Any user

Actions:

- Start a program -> wscript.exe
- Arguments -> C:\myWonkiePath\mySampleAppRunner.js

Conditions:

- Uncheck "Start the task only if the ..." and "Stop if the computer"...

Settings:

- Uncheck "Stop the task if it runs longer than:"

Comment: Ok, I will try this and let you know.  Thank you!  (I appreciate the specifics as far as checking whatever options/parameters in the creation of the task in Task Scheduler.  Unfortunately I had to learn those already the hard way from past experiences >.<)